# Exclude featured image from attachment loop

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, exclude, images

For my jigoshop theme I'm able to retrieve the images attached to my product post.  However it pulls all images from both the featured image and my metabox images.  What I'm trying to do is make it so that it excludes the featured image, but it's not working.  It also seems to be including other post featured images as well for some reason.

I tried [this suggestion](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-images-attached-to-posts-no-problem-but-need-to-remove-the-featured-image) with no luck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    global $_product, $post; 
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'exclude' => $thumb_id,
    'order' => 'asc'
    );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) :
        $loop = 0;

        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) :

            if ($thumb_id==$attachment->ID) continue;

            $loop++;

            $_post =  get_post( $attachment->ID );
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url($_post->ID);
            $post_title = esc_attr($_post->post_title);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
            $image = $image[0];
            $image_path =  thumbGen($image,500,0,"crop=1&halign=center&valign=center&return=1");
            $image_all = get_bloginfo('url').$image_path;
            $my_image = array_values(getimagesize($image_all));
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $my_image;            

            if ( ! $image || $url == get_post_meta($post->ID, 'file_path', true) )
                continue;

            echo '<span><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/></span>';

        endforeach;

    endif;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that set of arguments :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'post__not_in' => array( $thumb_id )
);
```

I'm using it for one of my site and it's working fine. So you shouldn't have to use :

```
 if ($thumb_id==$attachment->ID) continue;
```

in your loop.

Strangely, the `get_posts()` Codex Page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) says that we could use a `exclude` parameter, but also says that `get_posts()` use `WP_Query()`. And there is no `exclude` parameter in the Codex for `WP_Query()`(http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), only `post__not_in`.

So, let's use `post__not_in` instead of `exclude`.

Looks like a discrepancy.